# Magento 2.4.2 product isSalable not being set properly

Tags: magento2.4, inventory, salable

Using Magento 2.4.2-p2, I have a product that has stock and qty in the backend, but per the product->getData(), is_salable is set to `0` on the front end.

Per [this article](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/magento-2-3-Product-having-zero-salable-quantity-results-in/td-p/110753), I fully removed the inventory_stock_1 view and regenerated it, and the sku is visible in that table with the is_salable column set to 1, however after a reindex and cache clear, the front end still reports the is_salable is set to 0, and displays as OOS.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/347915/magento-2-4-2-product-issalable-not-being-set-properly/347923#347923

Answer (score 0):

This is related to multi-source inventory that has been added to the recent Magento version, to check if your product has been assigned to multisource inventory correctly you can go to the backend and have a look at this.

[image]

you can check by disabling the multisource inventory to check if that solves your issue, you can always enable it if it does not.

```
php bin/magento module:disable –f Magento_Inventory Magento_InventoryAdminUi Magento_InventoryApi Magento_InventoryBundleProduct Magento_InventoryBundleProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalog Magento_InventorySales Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi Magento_InventoryCatalogApi Magento_InventoryCatalogSearch Magento_InventoryConfigurableProduct Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryConfigurableProductIndexer Magento_InventoryConfiguration Magento_InventoryConfigurationApi Magento_InventoryGroupedProduct Magento_InventoryGroupedProductAdminUi Magento_InventoryGroupedProductIndexer Magento_InventoryImportExport Magento_InventoryIndexer Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotification Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationAdminUi Magento_InventoryLowQuantityNotificationApi Magento_InventoryMultiDimensionalIndexerApi Magento_InventoryProductAlert Magento_InventoryReservations Magento_InventoryReservationsApi Magento_InventoryCache Magento_InventorySalesAdminUi Magento_InventorySalesApi Magento_InventorySalesFrontendUi Magento_InventoryShipping Magento_InventorySourceDeductionApi Magento_InventorySourceSelection Magento_InventorySourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryShippingAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionAdminUi Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelectionApi Magento_InventoryElasticsearch Magento_InventoryExportStockApi Magento_InventoryReservationCli Magento_InventoryExportStock Magento_InventorySetupFixtureGenerator Magento_InventoryDistanceBasedSourceSelection
```

you can get more information about disabling it from here [link](https://bsscommerce.com/confluence/how-to-enable-disable-magento-2-multiple-source-inventory/)

Comment: Thanks @will-figueiredo - I turned off the MSI modules and can confirm that with MSI disabled, the product is purchaseable on the front end. While this fixes the immediate issue, the store we're using actually uses the MSI modules, so I need a solution to the oos issue that allows the MSI modules to be enabled. Re-enabling the MSI modules again shows the product as oos despite the inventory_stock_1 view showing is_salable as 1 for that sku. The Product Salable Qty section in the product record remains empty with or without the MSI modules enabled.